# How to send email in proper HTML format via iOS?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I have a simple web app which will trigger sending email using the "mailto" tag, but when the user does this on an iOS device, the email is always in plain text, I want the email format to be enforced to HTML, how would I accomplish this?

```
<a href="mailto:xxx@abc.com?subject=Test%20email;body=Action:Reject%0D%0A%0D%0ANote:">
```

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/message/17795770

Comment: I too am curious about this, even if anyone has an objective-c solution rather than web format!